# Javascript Date Compare - HTML Table with compare days ago

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple question But im totally lost. I have a table, data comes from mysql with php. I have to compare today with 10 days ago.

```
                   <div id="employee_table">  
                      <table class="sortable table table-bordered">  
                           <tr>  
                                <th width="10%">date1</th>  
                                <th width="10%">date2</th>  
                                <th width="10%">date3</th>
                                <th width="10%">date4</th>                                      
                           </tr>  
                           <?php  
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                           {  
                           ?>  
                           <tr>  
                                
                                <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row["date1"])) ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row["date2"])) ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row["date3"])) ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row["date4"])) ?></td>                                        
                           </tr>  
                           <?php  
                           }  
                           ?>  
                      </table>
```

If date less than 10 days date cell background will be red.

```
<script>
$(".employee_table").find('td').each(function() {
          // Parse the date
          var date = Date.parse($(this).text());
          console.log(date);
          // Create a date to compare against
          var fiveDaysAgo = new Date(new Date().getTime()-(10*24*60*60*1000));
          // Subtract 10 days from it
          var a = fiveDaysAgo.toISOString().replace(/T.*/,'').split('-').reverse().join('-')
                        console.log(a);

          var result = fiveDaysAgo.getTime();

          console.log(result);
          // Compare to see if the date in the table is older than 10 days
          if(result < date) $(this).css('background-color', '#CF202A');
        });
```

But this js code not change color correctly.
Anyone help ? Thank you!

how can i get same time format for table and 10 days ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little issue with the jQuery selector. Your `div` has an `id` attribute, not a `class` attribute.

Then, as your dates are produced in d-m-Y format, you cannot rely on `Date.parse`. Instead extract the date parts and create a date from it. You can use this operation to already add 10 days to it (or 5, like in your script).

You can compare this to the date of today, making sure the time component is ignored:

```js
// Get the date of today (midnight) once:
let today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
// Correct the selector:
$("#employee_table").find('td').each(function() {
    // Don't parse the string. Extract the date parts
    let [year, month, day] = $(this).text().split("-").reverse();
    // And create a date from it, adding already 5 days (day part can exceed 31)
    var date = new Date(+year, month-1, +day + 5);
    if (date < today) $(this).css('background-color', '#CF202A');
});
```

```html
<div id="employee_table">
    <table class="sortable table table-bordered">  
       <tr>  
            <th width="10%">date1</th>  
            <th width="10%">date2</th>  
            <th width="10%">date3</th>
            <th width="10%">date4</th>                                      
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
            <td>01-09-2021</td> 
            <td>4-09-2021</td> 
            <td>8-09-2021</td> 
            <td>12-09-2021</td> 
       </tr>  
    </table>  
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello again, how can i select spesific column with this solution ?

Comment: What do you mean with "select"? You mean as a jQuery collection of `td` elements?

Comment: example: i want check only date1 and date 3

Comment: `.find("td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(3)")`

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the date correctly as a JS `Date` object, you can just instantiate a new date based on 10 (or the amount of days you want) and compare them using `getTime()` divided by 86400000 (the amount of milliseconds in a single day)

See if below code helps you to get the logic.

```js
let currentDate = new Date()
let tenDaysAgo = changeDays(currentDate, -10)

function changeDays(date, daysToChange) {
  var newDate = new Date(date.getTime());
  newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + daysToChange);
  return newDate;
}

let daysDiff = (currentDate.getTime() - tenDaysAgo.getTime()) / 86400000

console.log(`Current Date: ${currentDate}`)
console.log(`10 days ago: ${tenDaysAgo}`)
console.log("Difference in days:", daysDiff)

if (daysDiff <= 10) {
  document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundColor = "#CF202A"
}
```

```css
#result {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```